# Azure Login on my Website

Tags: azure, authentication

Hey Guys i just quickly wanted to double check – as far as i know there is no way to implement the Microsoft Azure Login into an existing Website / Style – is this correct or is there any kind of work-around?

It really is annoying that customers need to "jump of" our page to azure to login in.

Comment: You need to provide more details about your scenario to understand better. Azure Web Apps uses the different types of authentication such as Azure Active Directory login, Facebook login, Google login, Twitter login and Microsoft Account login.
You can check this documentation for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview

Comment: i am not sure actually, i am a ui/ux designer and our developers told me that in order for our customers to login they need to visit this microsoft azure login site: 

https://i.imgur.com/1c3dJrI.png 

So this means if a user wants to login from our website he needs to click "login" on our site, then gets thrown off to the screen above and has to login there. This is super bad behaviour from both UX and UI of course. So i just want to double-check if there really is no way to have the login-logic implemented directly on our site (in our design) without creating a jump-off

Answer (score 0):

You can choose e.g. the background image. But, of course you can do the authentication back-end yourself, using the Microsoft Authentication libraries. See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios